# Why does my Fedora 14 system with an Intel Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller come up with the wrong aspect ratio?

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, intel-gma

I have a:

Compaq 610 VC275EA 15,6" WXGA i CELERON T1500

and I installed Fedora 14 on it. Everything is great, except one: the aspect ratio of the screen is not very good :\

http://pasted.co/cdeae
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dCbg5qNt
http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1165203

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
```

Can someone please say, that it cannot be fixed, or say: yes, it could be fixed, do xy, read xy, etc. :\ This is an issue for me for months now.. :\ Please help

Comment: Please include system information and other relevant bits directly in your post rather than via an external link (with bit.ly or otherwise). The external resource might vanish after a while, making the question useless to future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: "body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 141757"

Comment: well, yeah, please don't include _all_ of that, but summarize the important parts. Linking to a further gigantic dump after doing that is also okay (but hopefully unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two files to fix this:

- `/boot/grub/grub.conf` -- Remove `nomodeset`
- `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` -- Replace `vesa` with `intel`

Answer (score 2):

From your linked information, it appears you have an Intel GME965 integrated graphics controller. It appears the driver for that isn't working and you're getting the generic VESA driver. I suspect you're hitting this bug:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=650888

This suggests that the installer (incorrectly) put a `nomodeset` line in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. Edit that file (carefully) and remove that word wherever it appears.

Then, reboot and everything should Magically Just Work. (If that doesn't, try also removing any xorg.conf — `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, so that X starts with its defaults and automatic detection.)

Comment: thanks, i will try these 2 things out, but that will be in ~april. Thank you!!

Comment: @johnny8888: what will be in April? This solution should work now.

Comment: i mean i could only sit next to this pc in april.

Comment: @johhny I'd recommend moving as a safety precaution, `mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.my_safety_blanket`